# what is the difference between text classification and feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, feature-selection

can we select features without classification and if I have a text how can i know which are the features to choose? I need example regarding text not real word object example. if anyone can explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text Classification is classifying the text based on its features. For example, you might classify a sentence as having a positive ("I am so happy") or negative ("I am so sad") sentiment.

Text Feature selection is effectively deciding how you want to encode the text so you can run it through the classifier. There are many ways of doing this. For example, you could use a bag of words representation, where each column represents a word in your vocabulary and each cell represents how many times the word appears in the document.

If you had two sentences, "I am so happy, so very happy" and "I am so sad", your encoding for the sentences might be

| I || am | so | happy | very | sad |

1. 1. 2. 2. 1.   0.
2. 1. 1. 1. 1.   1.

Comment: Thanks for answering, how can i know that form the certain text which features i have to select? i.e what is the feature in this sentence  "I am so happy, so very happy"

Comment: @irfan The features you define are up to you. In the bag of words example above, the features are the number of times each word appears in the sentence. For example, happy appears twice in the first sentence so for that training example it'd have a value of 2. In the second example it only appears once so you'd have a value of 1.

Comment: yeah it is helpful, but  in real world we have much bigger data to deal with, so how i  get the features from them, how do i know they are actually are features?

Comment: @irfan when you have a lot of data (most of the time) you can generate these features automatically using a tool from a library such as scikit-learn's TfidfVectorizer.

Comment: so i dont have to do anything in feature selection ?

Comment: No, you'll still have to create these features with code, just not manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213573/discussion-between-irfan-and-mike).